# failed to use itextsharp to display pdf

Tags: itext

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var doc1 = new Document();
    string path = Server.MapPath("PDFs");
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(path + "AIA2.pdf", FileMode.Create));

    doc1.Open();
    doc1.Add(new Paragraph("My first PDF"));
    doc1.Close();
}
```

my task is to covert a pdf file as web contents, after that users can highlight any content in between the pdf file as summary, but i failed as first part,i failed to display my pdf file as web contents, as start my errors was path error which is location not found,but after i edited my path,it got no errors and outcome at all

Comment: The code you're using will save a PDF file to your disk, not send it to the browser.